# Can't import matplotlib on Anaconda (Python), on my Mac, even though it's installed on the terminal and set as a default

Tags: macos, python, ipython, matplotlib, anaconda

So basically on my Ipython I can't get it working even though it's installed, and the terminal shows that it should be working.

**Syntax and Error**

In [1]:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-eff513f636fd> in <module>()
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in <module>()
   1129 
   1130 # this is the instance used by the matplotlib classes
-> 1131 rcParams = rc_params()
   1132 
   1133 if rcParams['examples.directory']:

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in rc_params(fail_on_error)
    973         return ret
    974 
--> 975     return rc_params_from_file(fname, fail_on_error)
    976 
    977 

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in rc_params_from_file(fname, fail_on_error, use_default_template)
   1098         parameters specified in the file. (Useful for updating dicts.)
   1099     """
-> 1100     config_from_file = _rc_params_in_file(fname, fail_on_error)
   1101 
   1102     if not use_default_template:
```

**Terminal Feedback**

```
Last login: Fri Nov 27 03:05:21 on ttys001
Lorencs-MacBook-Pro-3:~ Lory$ conda install matplotlib
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: .....................
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at //anaconda:
#
matplotlib                1.5.0               np110py27_0    defaults
Lorencs-MacBook-Pro-3:~ Lory$
```

As you can see the matplot library is installed and already set as a default.

I spent a few hours on this, and I have no idea what's going on. Any help?

**Edit:**

- I can easily import other libraries, such as Numpy without issues.
- I'm using the 2.7 Python V., 64-bit.
- My OS X is Yosimite 10.10

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Basically, add some lines to your ~/.bash_profile:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Solution posted in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961239/pelican-3-3-pelican-quickstart-error-valueerror-unknown-locale-utf-8:

Comment: Links can become useless if the site goes offline or the article is deleted. Can you sum up the article if you believe it helps OP?

Comment: I followed the above step. I am able to import matplotlib.pyplot but now surprisingly the ipython command can't be found.
-bash: ipython: command not found

Comment: Thanks @JamieWilletts. You are right, but I only wrote the link in order to show the source, because I sum up in the former lines. I will change the link with the (same) solution posted in other StackOverflow post.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It fixed it by adding the two lines to the `.bash_profile` located in my user folder. Using TextEdit to open file.

Before editing: duplicate the `.bash_profile` for backup.

To see the hidden file:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

in the terminal window. Then reload:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```